# PIC18F XC8 compiler - objects not initialized?

Tags: pic, xc8

I have to use a Microchip PIC for a new project (needed high pin count on a TQFP60 package with 5V operation).

I have a huge problem, I might miss something (sorry for that in advance).
IDE: MPLAB X 3.51
Compiler: XC8 1.41

The issue is that if I initialize an object to anything other than 0, it will not be initialized, and always be zero when I reach the main();
In simulator it works, and the object value is the proper one.

Simple example:

```
#include <xc.h>
static int x= 0x78;
void main(void) {
   while(x){
     x++;
   }
   return;
}
```

In simulator the x is 0x78 and the while(x) is true. 
BUT when I load the code to the PIC18F67K40 using PICKIT3, the x is 0.

This happening even if I do a simple sprintf, and it does nothing as the formatting text string (char array) is full of zeros.
sprintf(buf,"Number is %u",x")

I can not initialize any object apart to be zero.
What is going on? Any help appreciated!

Comment: Even this will be a zero filled object: char txt[] = {"hello"};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem, The chip has an errata issues, and I got the one which is effected, strange, Farnell sells it. More strange that the compiler is not prepared for that, does not even give a warning to say to be careful!

Errata note:

> Module: PIC18 Core
>
> 3.1 TBLRD requires NVMREG value to point to
> appropriate memory
> The affected silicon revisions of the PIC18FXXK40
> devices improperly require the NVMREG<1:0>
> bits in the NVMCON register to be set for TBLRD
> access of the various memory regions. The issue
> is most apparent in compiled C programs when the
> user defines a const type and the compiler uses
> TBLRD instructions to retrieve the data from
> program Flash memory (PFM). The issue is also
> apparent when the user defines an array in RAM
> for which the complier creates start-up code,
> executed before main(), that uses TBLRD
> instructions to initialize RAM from PFM.

Comment: Yes, and works well. Need to set some bits to select proper source for copy.